# Can I use race track information in my application?

Tags: licensing, trademark

I`m developing a comercial app and I'm going to include some information about racetracks to it. I'm going to use follow information: a name of racetrack, a distance of one lap, names of turns. The app isn't a game.

I couldn't find any rules for using racetraks names. Some racetrack like Nürburgring belongs to commercial firms, so it names can be trademarks. What about are racetracks belong to goverments? Should I ask about licens for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

The pieces of information you are going to include are *facts*. Facts are not copyrightable.

The names will be trademarks but you will not be pretending to have any connection with them, so just using them for reference is fine.